# Query posts based on author id

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the current author id stored in `$theauthorid` I want to do a query based on the author id so I do this

```
query_posts('author=$theauthorid');
```

However it does not work unless I write the id manually. I know the id is stored correctly as I get the correct id when I echo it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is to get the variable outside the quotes. This way you can use either single or double quotes.

`query_posts( 'author=' . $theauthorid );`

Comment: Technically, that's not entirely true. `query_posts( "author=$theauthorid" );` will work just fine. The reason is that PHP interprets single and double quotes differently. In single quotes, all characters are literals; a $ is just a dollar sign, etc. But in double quotes, a $ means that a variable is about to follow.

Answer (score 0):

double quotes instead of single ones
([manual page](http://php.net/types.string) with explanation)

```
query_posts("author=$theauthorid");
```

but the whole approach is quite suspicious and possible dangerous
I bet we have trivial SQL injection here

I'd make it rather

```
 query_posts("author", $theauthorid);
```

with taking field name from array and value sanitizing